# Normalization of Scikit-learn MultinomialNB output

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

In **Scikit-learn** [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.predict_proba) it is possible to see that the **MultinomialNB** estimator has a method called **predict-proba** in which it has the following description: "Returns the **probability** of the samples for each class in the model. The columns correspond to the classes in sorted order, as they appear in the attribute classes_". This property is of my interest since I'm implementing a version of Multinomial Naive Bayes by myself in order to get more control over some assumptions I need to test in the supervised text classification problem. So, my question is: **How do they manage to normalize the output so that it is in the range between 0 and 1 for each class prediction?** I know that very often the denominator P(*d*), probability of the document *d*, in the general Naive Bayes equation isn't used at all, and the estimation gets the proportionality: argmax{c ∈ C} P(d|c)P(c). How can I implement this normalization? Any tips in Python programming language?

Thank you.